# SQL Server FOR XML format

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path, for-xml

Please, does someone knows how to write SQL FOR XML clause, if XML output requires this:

```
<element attribute="attribute_value">sub_element_or_value</element>
```

More info is on this question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163658/ms-sql-db-design-help

*DB is in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Don't post a more info link to another question. Add the content into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this you are looking for?

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, code VARCHAR(100),val VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @table  VALUES
 ('Code 1','Value 1')
,('Code 2','Value 2')
,('Code 3','Value 3')
,('Code 4','Value 4');

SELECT t.code AS [@code]
      ,t.val AS [*] 
FROM @table AS t
FOR XML PATH('element'),ROOT('elements');
```

The result

```
<elements>
  <element code="Code 1">Value 1</element>
  <element code="Code 2">Value 2</element>
  <element code="Code 3">Value 3</element>
  <element code="Code 4">Value 4</element>
</elements>
```